# How do I reference a DAL TableAdapter

Tags: asp.net

i am trying to build a little ASP.NET 3.5 project to explore DAL concepts.  While following the steps on this walkthrough:

http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs

I am unable to figure out how to reference the TableAdapter added in the DAL section from within the `App_Code` directory.  I tried adding the following different statements

```
using AccountsTableAdapter;

using <projectname>.App_Code.MyTableAdpater;
```

where `<projectname>` is the solution name.  When I add this to the code behind page but I keep getting an error regarding the namespace.  What is the pattern I need to use to find this code in 3.5 within the `App_Code` directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you create your project follow these steps :

- Add New Item >> Select "DataSet" from the window.
- you will see that a message displayed , Click Yes (this is to put you DAL in App_Data folder)
- if you haven't receive a dialog box that let you choose your database ,then go to Server Explorer and drag an drop you table ,
- Now you have a tables , go to you tutorial and follow it .

hope this helps